# how to change record from db before sending it to response in laravel model

Tags: laravel, api, model

I want to fetch a record(price) from db table and when sending it to api response I want to change it inside my model according to some conditions, I have searched and not found any relevant solution to this.

Comment: You found nothing about API resources in Laravel? That should do it

Comment: Please describe your query properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this?

```
$record = ModelName::find($id);
$record->price = $newValueBasedOnCondition;
$record->save();
```